# what does $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category') return in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, module, category, attributes

[image]

what does `$this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category') return` in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->_coreRegistry` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Registry` (vendor/magento/framework/Registry.php)

`register` method in `\Magento\Framework\Registry` register a new variable and store it in Registry.

`registry` method in `\Magento\Framework\Registry` returns the value of a `registered` variable in Registry otherwise, it returns `null`.

You can search in the Magento core directory (vendor/magento) with the search term: `->register('current_category'` to know which value is set to `current_category`.

Finally, you can see `$this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category')` return an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` or `null`.

So, if you visit a page that contains code register `current_category`:

```
$this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
```

you can get `current_category` from Registry:

```
$this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category')
```

Comment: I clearly understand, thank you so so much